# convert an 2d array from rows to blocks in any kind of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, block, sudoku

I need to convert rows and columns in a 2d array into blocks.

It should work on any matrix of size `n*n`, with any numbers that are given in the original array.

For example:

```
{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}};
```

Becomes:

```
{{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3}
{4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6}
{7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3}
{4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6}
{7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3}
{4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6}
{7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9}}
```

The amount of numbers to use for each block line is `sqrt(n)` - so as you can see in the example above, with each line in the array containing 9 numbers, each block line is composed of just 3 of those numbers.

Here is my code currently:

```
public static int[][] blocks(int[][] matrix, int sqrtN) {   
    int[][] blocks = matrix;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    while(counter+1<sqrtN){ 
        int n = sqrtN;//"n" will the size of the matrix.
        while(n<blocks.length){ 
            int t = counter;
            int j = 0;
            while(t<blocks.length){
                int k = n;
                if(t==counter & i%n==0 & i>0)
                    j= t-1;
                if(j%sqrtN==0)
                    i = 0;
                while(k==n || k%sqrtN!=0){
                    int temp = blocks[t][i];
                    blocks[t][i] = blocks[j][k];
                    blocks[j][k] = temp;
                    i= i+1;
                    k= k+1; 
                }
                j=j+sqrtN;
                t=t+sqrtN;          
            }
            n= n+sqrtN;
            counter= counter+1;

        }
        i=counter;
    }
    return blocks;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocks?

Comment: You posted your desired output. What output do you get?

Comment: ho sorry. by blocks I mean to convert the matrix like in the first example.  @CrazySabbath

Comment: and my output is do what I want half a way. @1blustone

Comment: Are you forced to do it inplace substitution? Can you create a separate array?

Comment: I can make a different array